# I have a gui with an axis and a push button

Tags: matlab, user-interface, axes, imshow

I have a gui with an axis and a push button, when I press the push button a video should play in the axis plot.. I have written this code but it is not being executed nor it is showing any errors.. Can anyone please help me..

```
    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    handles=guidata(hObject); 
    mov=VideoReader('VileParle.mp4');
    nFrames=mov.NumberOfFrames;
    for i=1:nFrames
      img=read(mov,i);
      imshow(img,[]);
    end
    guidata(hObject,handles)
```

Comment: If I put " figure(1) " in between the " img = read(mov,i) and imshow(img,[])" the video plays perfectly in a new figure window. But I don't want that, I want to play it in between the axis. Please help me.

Comment: add a `drawnow;` in your loop after the call to `imshow`.

Comment: @Hoki. You rock man. It worked perfectly. Thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your video with the correct plot area. 
I write my solution that worked for a normal plot in a FOR cycle (not attempted with real videos)

First, what is the name (handle) you gave to you plot area in you matlab GUI? I named it axes 1.

Second, I wrote the plot as an external function in an .m file called by the button, not a function in the button itself (consider this option but i think it can be done all in the callback)

Third, the code of the external function saved in a file *display_function.m*

```
  function [Output1, Output2] = display_function(mov, nFrames, axes1, handles )
    %output are optional in this case
    hg = hgtransform('parent', axes1);
    for i=1:nFrames
          img=read(mov,i);
          Frame(i) = imshow(img,[]); %plot the frame as an object
          set(Frame(i),'Parent',hg);
          drawnow
          pause(0.001);
          if (i>1)
            delete(Frame(i-1));
          end
    end
```

The function in the button should be called like that

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.mov=VideoReader('VileParle.mp4');
handles.nFrames=handles.mov.NumberOfFrames;
[handles.Output1, handles.Output2] =   display_function(handles.mov,handles.nFrames, handles.axes1);
```

NB I didn't use in my program `handles = guidata(hObject);`

Comment: Please find my comment as answer. As per restrictions to words, I have put my comment as answer.

Comment: @NipjyotiSarma Sorry, I think it was my fault: I copied it from my old script and I made a little error in the first line of the code (function declaration). Remember to save both .m files in the same folder (it is obvious but I did not say it). Check again the first line, change it, then tell me if it works. If it won't, I'll help you again!

Comment: @macrcoresk Yaa, I made those corrections but it was still not working. But as suggested by 'Hoki', the insertion of drawnow after imshow worked perfectly. Thank you for your feedback. :)

Comment: @NipjyotiSarma This is very strange, In fact I proposed the same solution (imshow + drawnow) with the management of handles, and it worked for me. But your results are more important than my pride. You are welcome. Consider upvoting the answer or the comment you found useful (the upward arrow in both cases) to give a "more pratical" thanks. :)